# libGdx getWorldHeight returning wrong value

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm creating a game using libGdx and I'm facing a difficulty with getWorldHeight() parameter. 
This is my code:

```
public Level(Viewport Viewport)
{
    this.viewport = Viewport;
    player = new Player(viewport,this);

    pbullets = new DelayedRemovalArray<PlayerBullet>();
    powerUps = new DelayedRemovalArray<PowerUps>();
    MediumAsteroid = new DelayedRemovalArray<Asteroid>();
    enemySpaceships = new DelayedRemovalArray<EnemySpaceShip>();

    startTime_POWERUP = TimeUtils.millis();
    startTime_ASTEROID = TimeUtils.millis();


    float Xpos = (viewport.getWorldWidth()/2);
    float Ypos = viewport.getWorldHeight();

    Gdx.app.log("YPOS ", Float.toString(Ypos));
    enemySpaceships.add(new EnemySpaceShip(new Vector2(Xpos,Ypos),this));


}
```

The world size is 128x128.
The Ypos, which is set to viewport.getWorldHeight() is returning 0.
However, in the same class, I call this method again during the update callback, and it returns 128. 
EXAMPLE:

```
public void SpawnPowerUp()
{
    float Xpos = MathUtils.random(Constants.POWERUP_WIDTH,viewport.getWorldWidth()) - Constants.POWERUP_WIDTH;

    float Ypos = viewport.getWorldHeight();

    Vector2 position = new Vector2(Xpos,Ypos);
    powerUps.add(new PowerUps(position,this));
}
```

For my knowledge, the viewport.getWorldHeight() should return the full world Height which is 128. Why is it returning 0 in this case?

Comment: how and from where you're creating viewport object ? `Level` constructor argument `(Viewport Viewport)`? make it correct

Comment: @AbhishekAryan I'm creating the viewport when the Screen is created with viewport = new ExtendViewport(Constants.WORLD_SIZE, Constants.WORLD_SIZE); then passing this to when the level is created

Comment: Probably Level object is created before viewport.update() is called and SpawnPowerUp is called after viewport.update()

Comment: `viewport.getWorldHeight()` should show you how much units of the world it shows in the Y axis. It's strange it returns 0, are you sure you setup the viewport correctly and not using very small units? One could show `0.16f x 0.9f` of the world if he wanted too and `0.9 / 2 == 0`. Perhaps you are creating your viewport without parameters until resize method and this level is asking for world height before it gets actually set properly?

Comment: @Madmenyo it only works normally when used in any other function that is not called during create() or show()

Answer (score 1):

Might be because in the constructor, create and show method the vp is not fully initialized yet. Did you try vp.apply()? I might test it today if I can find the time.

Comment: vp.apply() is done once the main screen render method is called. It worked when I changed the location from the constructor to the update method, and added a parameter to allow only one time use.